# Drawing a rectangle on CGContext without using subclass of UIView

Tags: iphone, drawing, cgcontext

How can I draw two different rectangles with black background without using subclass of `UIView` and using a `CGContext`?

Comment: Why such specific requirements? Why NOT a subclass, and why MUST it be drawing into a graphics context?

Comment: Because is an exercise that gave me my teacher at school, and I can't solve it

Comment: You perhaps ought to use the homework tag as well, then.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that there was a tag like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add whatever vanilla UIView objects you need in the appropriate positions, and set their background colours to whatever you like.

The drawing will be done in a CGContext, you just won't be able to control it.

Or, add a *CALayer* subclass of your own, set it to be the view's layer and draw your rectangles in there, in `drawInContext:`.

Or, set a different object as the delegate for the view's layer and draw it in the delegate method `drawLayer:inContext:`.

Comment: Thanks, though,you'll give me an example?

Comment: Try to work on what I've given you first. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions